# determining sensitivity of carbon monoxide sensor

Tags: sensor, smoke-sensor, gas

i'm working with a alphasense CO-AF sensor & i need to find out the CO quantity in ppm . i referred to the data sheet of the device and i dont know how to convert the given sensitivity
specification to ppm.here is the link to the [DATASHEET](http://www.alphasense.com/WEB1213/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/COAF.pdf).can anyone help me out.

Comment: It's the first line of the datasheet under PERFORMANCE : "Sensitivity nA/ppm in 400ppm CO 55 to 90"

Answer (score 4):

The sensitivity in the data sheet says that, for 1 PPM change in the gas concentration, there will be approximately 55 to 90 nA of current change. It is always relative and hence, initial calibration is very important. We are using several other gas sensors from the same vendor.

Comment: @Rajat do you mean this range: xxx ppm to delta +xxx ppm of CO can be measured.?